# Flutter navigator Question ! how to through a Button(in a page ) go to another navigative page?

Tags: flutter, navigation, navigationbar

what I want to do

[image]

I want to use a search button like on the top, go to another navigation page, and keep the navigativeBar,
 I try the navigator.push(), but it will go to a new page without the navigativeBar, 
What can I do?

Here is some of my code :

```
 return Scaffold(
      drawer: _buildDrawer(context),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: pageIx,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildBody(), Guanzhu(),
          Tansuo(),
          //Disan(list),
          Setting(), Dier()
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AnimatedBottomBar(
        onBarTap: (index) => setState(() => pageIx = index),
        barItems: widget.barItems,
        animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
        barStyle: BarStyle(fontSize: 20.0, iconSize: 30.0),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried wraping your NavBar with a Hero widget on both Routes?

Comment: @MohammadAssemNasser  e,I mean that click the search button then go to the search Navigation Item, but the hero is just a animation ,How can it work ?